# How do I get the compiler to read a downloaded library?

Tags: c++, compilation

I've downloaded OpenMesh for Linux Ubuntu. I successfuly compiled it following instructions at

*https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/openmesh_static/Documentations/OpenMesh-8.0-Documentation/a04067.html*

using cmake, then make. The result is a "build" folder containing, among other things, a makefile and .o files. I want to use OpenMesh in QT Creator, so I put an example code found on their website at

*https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/openmesh_static/Documentations/OpenMesh-8.0-Documentation/a04088.html*

basically it just displays a cube using cout and data structures I've downloaded. However, there are compilation errors of type "undefined reference to" everywhere.

Here is an example : "../OpenMesh-8.1/src/OpenMesh/Core/Mesh/ArrayKernel.hh:154: error : undefined reference to `OpenMesh::ArrayKernel::is_valid_handle(OpenMesh::HalfedgeHandle) const'

I think that this could be caused because I didn't tell the compiler somehow where I compiled OpenMesh, because someone else got this error at https://linuxfr.org/forums/programmation-c/posts/openmesh

I don't really get it, though, and I don't know much about the compiling process. I don't know how to import downloaded libraries and run them in QT. Does anyone know a simple way to do this ?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you look for this doc: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html ?

Comment: Did you also read the ["how to create your own project"](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/openmesh_static/Documentations/OpenMesh-8.0-Documentation/a04098.html) part of the documentation? Note the `target_link_libraries` part at the bottom.

Comment: I was, thanks so much for your help !

Comment: Turns out the correct way to do it was to open the file `CmakeLists.txt` in QT, and running the program. QT organized everything using the different `CmakeLists.txt` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to open `CmakeLists.txt` in qt creator, which organizes everything correctly.